# Replace \n with <br> with Liquid in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a csv with some formatting in cells and I wanted to preserve the line breaks. When I use the jsonify filter I can get the output where newlines have been added. ex: `This is some text \n and this is a new line`. I have a replace filter that replaces the newline character with a 
 tag, but it just clears the character and no line break is added: `replace: "\n", "<br>"`. I tried replacing the "\n" with js replace, but then the html doesn't get processed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course there's a filter for that: [newline_to_br](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/newline_to_br/) All I needed to do was add the filter to the raw output, no jsonify necessary. ex: `{{ data.info | newline_to_br }}`